# asp.net mvc4 route configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've create a very simple mvc4 application(visual studio's default internet application).
This is my RouteConfig class:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("anyRoute", "content/themes/staticcontent.html", new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" });
        routes.IgnoreRoute("content/themes/{filename}.html");
    }
}
```

When the url mySite.com/content/themes/staticcontent.html is entered I want the user to be redirected to mySite.com/Account/Register but I access the mentioned file.

Also I want to restrict users from accessing any html file at the mentioned directory except staticcontent.html but I can access that file too.

Comment: Are looking for authentication solutions, or prevent the access of static files? The route config is for routing only, not for authentication which should be handled elsewhere in your application.

Comment: I reckon that route configuration implies how to handle the requested url's. I want to serve the page mysite.com/Account/Register when user requests mysite.com/content/themes/staticcontent.html. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have tried it already, but what if you invert the two statements like:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.IgnoreRoute("content/themes/{filename}.html");
        routes.MapRoute("anyRoute", "content/themes/staticcontent.html", new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default ASP.NET MVC routing does not handle .html files. You would need to set this up in IIS first (see http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2013/08/29/asp-net-mvc-routing-intercepting-file-requests-like-index-html-and-what-it-teaches-about-how-routing-works.aspx) and then then routing would work.

If it is just a single file that needs to be redirected, it would be simplest to just set up a 301 or 302 redirect in IIS.